# Blazor rendering of table column widths

Tags: html, razor, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a Microsoft Blazor project. I'm trying to get Razor to change the column widths of a table dynamically. I couldn't get it to work, so I created this very stripped down version for testing. The following code creates two tables. In the first one, there is no Razor code and the widths render correctly. In the second, the widths are ignored, even though they are hard-coded. In the non-stripped down version, I set the visibility of the column and the text of the header using Razor and it works fine. It's only the width that is ignored.

```
    <table>
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th WIDTH="100">Column 1</th>
                <th WIDTH="200">Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var col in Columns)
                {
                    <th WIDTH="300">Column 1</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      ...
```

[image: Resulting column headers]

Comment: The width is not ignored it's the normal browser interpretation when there's too much column to display. Reduce the number of column to 2 and you'll get the difference. That's not a blazor specific behavior, you'll obtain the same with jquery or a js function.

Comment: I forgot to say it's because each column has the same width

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I need some way to control the width of the columns regardless of how many there are. The whole table does not need to be displayed on the screen at once. The user can scroll. In fact, that's what happens now. Only part of the table is displayed and the user scrolls right to see the rest. The browser reduces the column widths despite this. There must be some way to override this behavior. I tried setting the width attribute on various div's in the enclosing components, but it has no effect.

Comment: overflow-x: auto on the thead my be

Comment: actually a table is design to display each column, not to scroll. Or set the table width with the sum of colums width

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Instead of using text for the table headers, I used buttons with borders set to none and margins set to 0. Looks just like text, but now I can control a column width by setting the button width.